# Is it possible to auto change the size of group elements when the window size changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the sample of my layout:

[image]

It is possible to have a fixed size elements and then when the window size changes, the elements also changes its size (and also all the paddings, margins and stuff).

Lastly, is there a way to set a limit on how small the group of elements can be?

Comment: I think responsive layouts might help. You can also get by using `%` but you might have to write media queries. Read about responsive design. I think it might answer some of your preliminary questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to set a limit on how small the group of elements can be?

`min-width` css property is exactly what you need.

> It is possible to have a fixed size elements and then when the window size changes, the elements also changes its size (and also all the paddings, margins and stuff).

the `percentage` value can help you achieve that functionality.

> The  CSS data type represents a percentage value. It is often used to define a size as relative to an element's parent object. Numerous properties can use percentages, such as width, height, margin, padding, and font-size. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible. you have to use percentage instead of px.